# Use rm function in function

Tags: r

I have a problem to use rm function. A minimal example of rm would be like:

```
env <- new.env()
assign("v", 3, envir = env)
ls(env)
> [1] "v"
rm("v", envir = env)
ls(env)
> character(0)
```

However, if I want to wrap rm function, then I face a problem:

```
rm_wrapper <- function(val, envi){rm(val, envir = envi)}
> rm_wrapper("v", env)
Warning message:
In rm(val, envir = envi) : object 'val' not found
> ls(env)
[1] "v"
```

I wonder how to fix this problem, and why it happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `rm()` a named object such as `val`, it will attempt to remove the object named `val` in the specified environment. However, you can use `rm()`'s "list" option to give it a character vector of names of objects to remove; from `help("rm")`:

> Arguments
>
> ...    the objects to be removed, as names (unquoted) or character
>   strings (quoted).
>
> list   a character vector naming objects to be
>   removed.

So, we do this:

```
rm_wrapper <- function(val, envi){rm(list = val, envir = envi)}
env <- new.env()
assign("v", 3, envir = env)
rm_wrapper("v", env)
ls(env)
# character(0)
```

We could alternatively make sure the character vectors you're sending your `rm()` wrapper are not named objects, like so:

```
rm_wrapper <- function(..., envi){rm(..., envir = envi)}
env <- new.env()
assign("v", 3, envir = env)
rm_wrapper("v", envi = env)
ls(env)
# character(0)
```

Comment: I understand! thanks!